# List Subtraction in Python

Tags: python, list, set, logic

I've got a comma delimited text file with content that's kinda like this:

```
pickle_4500@dill.chile, pickle_4501@dill.chile, pickle_4502@dill.chile, pickle_4503@dill.chile, pickle_4504@dill.chile, pickle_4505@dill.chile
```

Let's call it `emails1.csv`. I've got another comma delimited text file too:

```
pickle_4503@dill.chile, pickle_4505@dill.chile
```

Let's call it `emails2.csv`. I need to subtract `emails2.csv` from `emails1.csv` using Python. In pseudocodenese:

```
emails1.csv = emails1.csv - emails2.csv
```

---

Total virgin to Python, but I made this based on a couple examples I found. Does it do what I think it does? That is, take the emails in `emails2.csv` out of `emails1.csv` and put the difference in a file called `subtractomatic.csv`.

```
from sets import Set
import csv

fin = open('emails1.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(fin)
email_list1 = list(reader)[0]

fin = open('emails2.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(fin)
email_list2 = list(reader)[0]

email_list1 = list(set(email_list1)-set(email_list2))

fout = open('subtractomatic.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
writer.writerow(email_list1)

fout.close()

fin.close()
fin.close()
```

I think it does because my original file, namely `emails1.csv`, has `X` emails in it, and when I open `subtractomatic.csv` there are emails in it, and when I run

```
grep @ -o subtractomatic.csv | wc -l
```

in the terminal I get `X/2`, which makes sense because `emails1.csv` has twice as many emails as `emails2.csv`---by design. I am, however, also a novice, so I don't know that I'm looking at this thing right.

Comment: You can do the following: `list_a = list(set(list_a) - set(list_b))`

Comment: To be clear, the "=" above is a reassignment operator.

Comment: Hi PicklePilot, welcome to StackOverflow! I've added the proper code formatting to your question and removed some of the extra text not related to your question. Please look over our FAQ. If you could explicitly spell out what you expect the result to be, you'll get the answer that matches your expectations.

Comment: "psuedocodenese" was coined by Pickle_Pilot on Wed Feb 18 20:50:27 PST 2015 and is potentially pending registration with the US Patent and Trademark Office, if I feel like it. ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to find the difference between two lists and then assign the results back to the list 1. The sets module provides classes for constructing and manipulating unordered collections of unique elements. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing standard math operations on sets such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.

```
>>> l1 = ['pickle_4500@dill.chile', 'pickle_4501@dill.chile', 'pickle_4502@dill.chile', 'pickle_4503@dill.chile', 'pickle_4504@dill.chile', 'pickle_4505@dill.chile']
>>> l2 = ['pickle_4503@dill.chile', 'pickle_4505@dill.chile']
>>> set(l1)-set(l2)
{'pickle_4500@dill.chile', 'pickle_4502@dill.chile', 'pickle_4504@dill.chile', 'pickle_4501@dill.chile'}
>>> list(set(l1)-set(l2))
['pickle_4500@dill.chile', 'pickle_4502@dill.chile', 'pickle_4504@dill.chile', 'pickle_4501@dill.chile']
>>> l1 = list(set(l1)-set(l2))
>>> l1
['pickle_4500@dill.chile', 'pickle_4502@dill.chile', 'pickle_4504@dill.chile', 'pickle_4501@dill.chile']
```

Comment: I'm going to be completely honest with you, Avinash Raj, I checked yours because I like your avatar... ^_^

Comment: Actually, I take that back, I checked yours because I like your avatar when it's small. I thought it was a green samurai-cyclops with three upward pointing teeth, but when I click on it, and it's bigger, it's not that interesting. Not sure why I'm telling you this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets:

```
difference = set(listA) - set(listB)
```

Comment: ...and you can use `sorted` if you care to keep the list in sorted order afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the *all* set approach used by others, you can make `B` a `set` and filter out it's contents from `A`:

```
b_set = set(B)
a_filtered = [a for a in A if a not in b_set]
```

This has the advantage of keeping the order of `A` in `a_filtered` (sans the elements you want to remove)...

Comment: You mean to say `if a not in b_set`? Besides, why change `B` to a set at all? You can use `B`, which is a list, as it is right?